# posting different file types to different php blocks on php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have the following code in php:

```
 if (isset($_FILES)) {
     foreach($_FILES as $index => $picture)
     {
     echo $_FILES;
     }
  }
```

JavaScript code to post form data:

```
$(".update").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
    url: 'submit.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType:false,
    processData: false,
    data: function(){
        var data = new FormData();
        jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
            data.append('file-'+i, file);
        });
        data.append('body' , $('#body').val());
        return data;
        }(),
        success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr, result, errorThrown){
        alert('Request failed.');
       }
       });
       $('#picture').val('');
       $('#body').val('');
      });
```

**html form**:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="myform">
<textarea name="body" id="body" class="texarea" placeholder="type here">
</textarea>

<label for="photo" class="custom-file-upload">
<i class="fa fa-picture-o"style="font-size:20px;color:pirple;"></i>
</label>
<input id="file" name="picture[]" type="file"  multiple/>
//this is my part of interest now
<label for="docs" class="docsmsg">
<i class="fa fa-file" style="font-size:20px;color:red;"></i>
</label>
<input id="docs" name="document[]" type="file"  multiple/>
</form>
```

The PHP code does not receive files with a particular name attribute from the form but any file whether it be photo, document or different names. 
if (isset($_FILES))

However, this is not what I want. On my form, I want two or even three file input options just like the one above except that the other would be meant to upload documents only and the last one to upload like videos only...notice where I put the note...saying...'this is my part of interest.' this is the new addition i want to add.

The current one is to upload photos only...but i am interested in  three file input options...one for photos, videos, documents.

Initially I tried to distinguish the different using this php code :

```
  if (isset($_FILES[file])) {
  //do something
  }
```

but that did not work. It was not doing the 'something.' it's only until i remove the [file] description at the end in the square brackets, then it started to do the 'something' as indicted above.

My question really is, based on what i want to achieve....which is having multiple multiple file inputs for different types of file individually, how do i allow php to actually determnine which of the form input field the files are being attached or which/what file types do I want to process.
As the code is now, it does not matter which input field the files are being attached but at the end, they all come to that one if (isset($_FILES)) instruction....

Comment: ```$_FILES[file]``` -- the variable file would have to contain a valid index to the $_FILES array. To test for a particular file type, you have to get the filename, and test it's extension or mime type. There are lots of examples for doing just that on the web in general, and SO specifically.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: this link may not work for me....remember that i am trying to get multiple files with a particular name to be sent to the php file....multiple files coming from one input field and not multiple input fields.......two multiple input fields for two different type of files with different names...each field must accept multiple uploads for that file type at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello_ mate,

first I see a mistake here `if (isset($_FILES[file]))` this will never work because you need quotes like this `if (isset($_FILES['file']))`. Then when you **POST** your form, the data is coming with `name` attributes and not `id`, so if you have this **HTML**:

```
<input id="file" name="picture[]" type="file"  multiple/>
<input id="docs" name="document[]" type="file"  multiple/>
```

In `PHP` you would do:

```
if(isset($_FILES['picture'])){
    foreach($_FILES['picture'] as $fileData){ 
        // process your picture files here
    }
}

if(isset($_FILES['document'])){
    foreach($_FILES['document'] as $fileData){ 
        // process your document files here
    }
}
```

and **NOT**:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
}

if(isset($_FILES['docs'])){
}
```

I hope you get the point. Good luck :)

**NOTE**

Have in mind that you should validate the file type manually when checking the `type` property. When you have multiple files selected you will receive data in the following structure:

```
[picture] => Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => icon.ico
            [1] => some-png.png
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => image/x-icon
            [1] => image/png
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => \tmp\php3F40.tmp
            [1] => \tmp\php3F41.tmp
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 370070
            [1] => 370070
        )

)
```

So you can do something like this for example:

```
$imgsAllowedTypes = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/bmp');

if(isset($_FILES['picture'])){
    // This is an array of uploaded files 
    $pictures = $_FILES['picture'];
    $fileNames = $pictures['name'];
    foreach($fileNames as $k => $fileName){
        // Here you can access other properties of the file by index - $k
        $fileType = $pictures['type'][$k];
        $tmpName = $pictures['tmp_name'][$k];
        $error = $pictures['error'][$k];
        $size = $pictures['size'][$k];
        if(!in_array($fileType, $imgsAllowedTypes)){
            // Invalid image 
            continue;
        }

        // upload 
        move_uploaded_file($tmpName, 'path/where/you/save/files/filename.extension');
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Okay now thanks to your comment I can admit that I didn't checked your `javascript` code and when I didn't I can say that it is wrong, if you want the code snippet that I wrote to work you should have the following javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: function () {
        // Note the change is here
        // You should have the same names set in the FormData object
        // as you are waiting in the PHP script
        var data = new FormData();
        $.each($('#file')[0].files, function (i, file) {
            data.append('picture[' + i + ']', file);
        });

        $.each($('#docs')[0].files, function (i, file) {
            data.append('document[' + i + ']', file);
        });
        return data;
    }(),
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, result, errorThrown) {
        alert('Request failed.');
    }
});
```

Read the comment for details

Comment: Just a small note - PHP will actually convert the file and docs array indexes to strings and trigger a warning - or at least it behaved that way in much of version 5, so that code actually would work (although with warnings). It is definitely bad practice and is unfortunately still supported in PHP 7.

Comment: After reading your solution, I tried the following code but still no luck:  the php <?php
if(isset($_FILES['picture'])){
    foreach($_FILES['picture'] as $fileData){ 
        echo $fileData;
    }
}
?> and the html form <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> <input id="file" name="picture[]" type="file"  multiple/></form> What is the error now? The file does not echo. I also did not change the javascript above since you did not identify an issue.

Comment: @maraj try `echo '<pre>'.print_r($fileData, true).'</pre>';` instead `echo $fileData` you can't directly `echo` an `array`

Comment: @maraj I really didn't checked your `javascript`, but now I see why it is not working. Please check the edit in couple of minutes

Comment: @maraj you can check not the **EDIT** and use again `echo '<pre>'.print_r($fileData, true).'</pre>';` to see what you are uploading. Good luck, hope this was helpful for you!

Comment: not working for me...after i click on the submit button, the page refreshes...i don't see the pop up.

Comment: @maraj page refreshes because you need to put `return false` on the bottom of the click handler to prevent the default behavior and not to submit the `<form>` or use something that is different from `<input type="submit">` or `<button>` e.g. `<span class="update">`

Comment: i added the return false just like you said. it still did not work..i do not even see the pup up based on the javascript. To prove that it is working on your end, can you post the codes somewhere so that when i click, i can view a demonstration as an example?

Comment: that worked now...however, when i try to test the file type in php as you suggested above, it says  that type is an undefined index... ..you can try it and see..what's wrong now?

Comment: @maraj I did edit the post again, to show you the structure of data that is coming in $_FILES when you upload multiple files and did corrected the file type validation sample - check it out :)

Comment: this seemed to work actually. I do appreciate the assistance very highly.. Let inform you where needed if anything again.

Comment: Yes, sure. I just hope that you are understanding the code and it is helpful for you to learn new stuff. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just as a pre-cursor, I believe the contentType must be set to 'multipart/form-data' in the AJAX request as well.

Now, onto your question in regards to the PHP side of things. It really depends how you want to architect the code for the upload as to how you must write your code - which is obviously, well, obvious.

So here's what I would do.

Let's say we have an endpoint for the files to be uploaded to - I see you have not given one in your form, so I will name it 'upload.php' for simplicity sake.

I have 3 types of fields. Pictures, Documents and Videos. The HTML markup would be very simple.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="picture[]" />  <!-- 1 or more -->
    <input type="file" name="video[]" />    <!-- 1 or more -->
    <input type="file" name="document[]" /> <!-- 1 or more -->
</form>
```

Of course, you will want to expand on this very basic form. Each input field could be duplicated for more upload fields.

Now, to the PHP. I will omit the JavaScript, as it seems you have a handle on that.

```
<?php
    if (empty($_FILES)) {
        // We could output an error here if we like...
        // Let's just end execution.
        die();
    }

    // Will we process any pictures?
    if (!empty($_FILES['picture'])) {
        // Yes, we are processing a picture upload.
        // _FILES[picture] is an array of arrays, let us iterate!
        foreach ($_FILES['picture'] as $picture) {
            // In here, we process each picture.

            // Make sure the upload is ok
            if ($picture['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                // Process the error
            }

            // Before we save this, we should perform some MIME sniffing...
            // I'll leave the implementation to you, just DON'T use picture['type'], as it is unreliable
            $verified = false;
            if (!$verified) {
                // Note the error then break to continue processing other photos.
                break;
            }

            // We should move the file to our uploads directory
            move_uploaded_file($picture['tmp_name'], 'OUR_UPLOADS_DIR/myfile.jpg');

            // Maybe here you can note a successful upload?
        }
    }

    // How about some documents?
    if (!empty($_FILES['document'])) {
        foreach ($_FILES['document'] as $doc) {
            // Here, we should basically do the same as with the picture.
            // - Check for an error
            // - Sniff the MIME type to ensure it's a safe file
            // - Move the file
        }
    }

    // Finally, we can do the same for the videos
    if (!empty($_FILES['video'])) {
        // You get the idea :)
    }

    // Now, we should actually output a response to the AJAX request,
    //  so we may notify the client of what actually happened.
    //  Success, or failure? I'll leave this up to you, to choose how
    //  best to communicate back to the client.
```

As you can see, handling files in PHP can be very easy. But to do it properly, does require some proper groundwork. As a lot of this code is very much the same, it may be useful to you to create a helper function rather than typing the same code out 3 times.

Comment: for some reason, when I try this solution, after clicking the submit button, the page refreshes. I did not see the pop up based on the javascript code i posted as part of the question. What's wrong?

Comment: I assumed you would be able to make the Javascript work as you seemed to have a handle on that. You should be attaching the javascript to the submit event on the form.